# Creating time windows with Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, time-series, enumerable

Having an array of several time series (timestamp, value) like this:

```
time_series = [[[1234567, 0.8], [1234568, 0,9], [1234569, 1.0]], 
               [[1234568, 0,7], [1234569, 0,2], [1234570, 1.2]],
               [[1234560, 0,9], [1234561, 0.2], [1234568, 0,1]]]
```

I want to create an array of time windows of a given size `time_size`. For example, if I wanted to create time windows of `time_size = 2`:

```
    time_size = 2
    time_windows = create_time_windows(time_series, time_size)
    puts time_windows
#   time_windows => [[[], [], [[1234560, 0,9], [1234561, 0.2]]],
#                    [[[1234567, 0.8], [1234568, 0,9]], [[1234568, 0,7], [[1234568, 0,1]]],
#                    [[[1234569, 1.0]], [[1234569, 0,2], [1234570, 1.2]], []]]
```

I know it is not a very readable example, but the operation can be summarized as splitting an array of time series into an array of subarrays containing the segments of those time series whose timestamp is included into the pertinent interval of time.

In the example, I wanted to do that with a time window size of `2`, so I picked the earliest time of the whole array of series, and began to count from there. So, my first time window contains all points from the three earlier series whose timestamp was included between `1234560` (the origin in my series, because the earlier point was that) and `1234560 + 2`. You can see that the first window doesn't have elements from the first and second series, since there are no points whose timestamp was included within the interval. The next interval would be (`1234560 + 2`, `1234560 + 4`), and so on.

I am not specially proficient in Ruby, so I would be glad if the community can help me solving this problem. I have considered using `Enumerable` methods such as `slice_when` combined with `inject`, but I got impossibly lost trying to code that.

Comment: Why you have 3-element arrays in main input array, which in turn contain `[timestamp, value]` array?  Why not 9-element array where each element is array of `[timestamp, value]`?  Same way, I am unable to interpret the expected output.

Comment: Because each 3-element array is a temporal series itself, you can see them as the output of three different sensors in an interval of time. `time_series = [signal_from_accelerometer, signal_from_heart_rate_monitor, signal_from_electrodermal_sensor]`